# Tkinter Scrollbar not showing

Tags: python, tkinter

So I've tried a bunch of different solutions from threads I've searched here. Here is my code:

```
def begin():

    global path, thumbPath, fullImgPath, running
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("keyBuilder")

    frame = Frame(root, width = 630, height = 450)
    frame.pack()

    exitButton = Button(frame, text="Exit keyBuilder", width=10, command=exitProgram)
    exitButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    Running = True
    b = Button(frame, text="Set Directory Path", width=20, command=getPath)
    b.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    groupMenu = Frame(frame, width = 150)
    tree = Treeview(groupMenu, selectmode = 'browse')
    tree.pack(fill = Y)
    tree.insert(parent = '', index = 'end', text = 'Master')
    a = tree.insert(parent = '', index = 'end', text = 'Group 1')
    tree.insert(parent = a, index = 'end', text = 'Slide 1')

    yscrollbar = Tkinter.Scrollbar(frame, orient = VERTICAL)
    numImages = 0
    for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path + '/imgThumb/', '*jpg')):
        numImages += 1
    COLUMNS = 4
    image_count = 0

    gallery = Canvas(frame, width = COLUMNS * THUMB_SIZE, height = COLUMNS * THUMB_SIZE, yscrollcommand = yscrollbar.set)#
    yscrollbar.config(command = gallery.yview)
    for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path + '/imgThumb/', '*.jpg')):
        print "filling gallery with: " + infile
        image_count += 1
        r, c = divmod(image_count-1, COLUMNS)
        im = Image.open(infile)
        tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
        myvar = Label(gallery, image=tkimage)
        myvar.image = tkimage
        gallery.create_window(c*THUMB_SIZE, r*THUMB_SIZE, anchor = NW, window = myvar)
    gallery.config(scrollregion=gallery.bbox(ALL))
    yscrollbar.config(command = gallery.yview)
    groupMenu.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    gallery.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    yscrollbar.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
    yscrollbar.config(command = gallery.yview)
    root.mainloop()
```

and here are all of the packages I'm using which might have something to do with the issue:

```
import pymongo
import glob, os
from subprocess import Popen
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import zipfile
import shutil
```

I've tried setting up the scrollbar and the canvas, and populating the canvas in many different orders. I've tried giving the canvas specific scroll regions. I just can't seem to get the scrollbar to work.

Thanks!

Comment: An advice, without reading your question completely or looking at your code, do not import Tkinter and ttk using global imports, use `import ttk` for the second module.

Comment: Ok, so it would just be "import ttk" and than when I use the tree widget later on use "ttk.Tree"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But, to be honest, I don't know if this will solve your particular problem, since I have not read your question completely yet...

Comment: Thanks, it's definitely not related to the scrollbar but I could see how it could have caused other issues in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. I had to add

```
sticky = NE + SE
```

as an argument to

```
yscrollbar.grid()
```

and place the scroll bar in a column one to the left of the column holding the canvas being scrolled.

I think the scrollbar was always there but the grid geometry manager placed it somewhere that I couldn't access.